# Kriegen ist ein Kampf?

Tags: meaning-in-context

In German when one says *kriegen* (stronger than just *bekommen*), was it in some olden day context, that to earn anything it was a struggle?  Curious to ask because  *Krieg* means war.

Don't know if the question is even polite.

Comment: Why shouldn't it be not polite to ask a reasonable question?

Comment: Today there is prosperity and law. I was referring only to the distant past..  to denote grave danger : in my own native Indian language one says " the house is submerged in (flood) water "...  a catch phrase to desperately announce arrival  of the worst feared danger.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could say so. There was a verb "kriegen" in middle high German that meant "make an effort, strive, struggle", obviously related to the noun "Krieg". Also, based on that, there was a weak verb "erkriegen" meaning "strive, attain, seek to attain".

From around the 14th century, "erkriegen" and "kriegen" were also used in the sense of "obtain, receive, get". "Erkriegen" has morphed into today's "kriegen".

Source and more information (in German): https://www.dwds.de/wb/kriegen#etymwb-1 (Etymologisches Wörterbuch by Wolfgang Pfeifer)